# My laptop's fan is buzzing

Tags: fan

My laptop's fan is making a loud sound similar to buzzing and even vibrates. Could someone tell me if I just have to clean the dust inside the laptop box or I have to take it to a specialist?

Comment: This will be closed as it asks for opinions. Since you seem able, blow the dust and see if it helps, although ....

Comment: actually there are A LOT of questions like mine in here, I just didn't find an appropriate suggestion so I added one more

Answer (score 1):

It could be due to a  **bad bearing**    in fan or **due to dust**. Either way you can fix it.
If you're not comfortable opening the laptop up and inspecting/replacing parts, I would suggest taking it into the shop.

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the fan yourself, call the OEM and see if they'll send you a new one.

Comment: Awkay, I guess I should try it.. Actually I came across this suggestion a few times and obviously I do have to try it thanks though \/

Comment: Most fans these days have either ball bearings or sleeves of oil, when either breaks down, you just have to replace it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to open the laptop by yourself, cleaning it and fix it if, by chance, some parts have somewhat loosened.

If you still have problems, you can buy a replacement part (I would suggest trying ebay) and substitute it, usually it's a very simple work. If you are unsure on how to do it properly, you can look in your laptop's manufacturer's website for your specific model "disassembling manual", "service manual", or the like.
You can also try to search sites like http://www.ifixit.com/ or http://www.fixya.com/ for specific guide for your model.